# Setup a macOS VM in Parallels from recovery partition without company defaults from Remote Management

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop, vmware, virtualbox

I started a new job as software developer a few months ago, and I got a company MacBook Pro for work from home that I'm also allowed to use privately.

I haven't used a MacBook before so given the chance I'm trying to get into the basics of macOS development.

I wanted to test a simple application that I developed, on a clean virtual machine. At first I tried to setup a VM with VirtualBox but I couldn't find a legit source for a clean macOS image, e.g., nowadays you can download an official Windows 10 ISO directly from Microsoft, but I couldn't find one for macOS. I found something that seemed like a suitable alternative in "Parallels Desktop 17 for Mac" which I haven't used before either. I purchased a license, and it allowed me to create a macOS VM on my MacBook from its recovery partition. That seemed fine so far, although I ran into two major problems.

1. I couldn't download the newest version of macOS (Monterey at the time of writing) because my device administrator doesn't allow that version yet. Fair point to use an older, more stable version as a daily driver but that doesn't really matter for a VM.
2. I was able to install Big Sur until "Remote Management" prompted me to login with my companies account to "automatically configure your computer". I probably shouldn't do that because I don't want to register multiple MacBooks with my credentials at the Remote Management service. Furthermore then it's not a clean VM anymore if it installs all that proprietary software and changes the defaults of countless settings.

So is there a way to get a clean macOS ISO from a legit source, or to ignore the whole device administration stuff when setting up a VM in Parallels? How do macOS developers usually deal with that?

Comment: I have installed Monterey in a (free for personal use) VMware virtual machine using software from *"a legit source for a clean macOS image"*. The legit source being Apple. The newest version of macOS that I have installed in VirtualBox is Mojave. Actually, I use VMware to create the macOS installers for VirtualBox. Although you could also use a flash drive.

Comment: Check out the help on OS X daily: https://osxdaily.com/where-download-macos-installers/